# Screen clipping on Android

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm using libgdx with the goal to create a simple platform game. The player is bound by the width of the screen. Here is the player in the initial position:

[image: img]

When I set the player's X position to 0 (I'm aware that doesn't take into account the width of the sprite, I've yet to come to that but I am aware) it looks like this:

[image: img2]

Notice the gap between the sprite and the edge of the screen? What's the issue with that? When I run the game as a desktop application, resize the window I find that the gap can get bigger or smaller and can even result in a gap at the bottom as so:

[image: img3]

Here is what I set the project up as in the `create()` method:

```
public void create() {
        ...

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(9, 16, camera);

        ...

    }
```

I thought by using the viewport I set the aspect ration 9:16 for my phone in portrait mode and it would adapt to that but that doesn't seem to be the case. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I elected for a `StretchViewport` instead of a `FitViewport` and the game now behaves as I desired.